# uFlex save custom data

Tags: php, user-management

I want to use uFlex(http://ptejada.com/projects/uFlex) for my user management but I can't get it working :(

I try to send this data via post:

```
 Array data:[{"username":"jo"},{"email":"test@yahoo.de"},{"password":"password"},{"clientTel":"123"},{"clientAddress":"Address"},{"clientBillingInfo":"bill"},{"clientNotes":"note"},{"clientID":"Gm5ImzGy3ux9681n8MfFYhSzwjixM0tvXnldO4lr"}]
```

but uFlex always returns these errors:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in      <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iGimbalManager/Manager2.0/uflex/class.uFlex.php</b> on line   <b>1210</b><br />
<br />

<b>Warning</b>:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iGimbalManager/Manager2.0/uflex/class.uFlex.php</b> on line <b>1210</b><br />

if($args){
            $st->execute($args);
            $this->report("SQL Data Sent: [" . implode(', ',$args) . "]"); //Log the SQL Query first
        }
```

I can't find the error. Maybe some of you knows a good user management php class, or someone can help me with uFlex here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that users table field names match input fields letter case, i.e.: if Table's username field is 'Username', input field would be: .

If above didn't work, use $user->filter() to filter which inputs the user class needs to care about:

```
$user->filter('Username', 'Email', 'Password', 'Password2', 'GroupID');
```

In general, the demo with the package is great place to start with.